# Spring RestRemplate postforobject with request parameter having integer value

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, resttemplate

I have a method in  Spring rest service.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "test/process", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody MyResponse processRequest(String RequestId, int count)
```

I am using Spring RestTemplate to call this service like this.

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = this.getRestTemplate();
MultiValueMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
map.add("RequestId", RequestId);
map.add("count", count); 
restTemplate.postForObject(url, map,MyResponse.class);
```

When I try to invoke the client method I get the exception that **no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [java.lang.Integer]**

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [java.lang.Integer]
at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.writePart(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:310)
at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.writeParts(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:270)
at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.writeMultipart(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:260)
at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.write(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:200)
at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.write(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:1)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$HttpEntityRequestCallback.doWithRequest(RestTemplate.java:596)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:444)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:409)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:287)
```

I know one of the ways is to pass all the parameters as String. But I might need to pass complex data types as parameters later. 
What is the ways to achieve this.
I have googled and some option seem to be writing my own converters. How should I start about solving this problem.

Comment: In the following line:

    map.add("RequestId", RequestId);

is RequestId an object more complex than a string?

Can we see the URL?

Thanks!

Comment: @java1337 RequestId is currently just a string but I might need to post a custom data types or a date object in other methods

Answer (score 7):

The root cause of this error is that by specifying an `Integer` in the `LinkedMultiValueMap`, the `RestTemplate` will take that to mean that your request is a multipart request. There is no `HttpMessageConverter` registered by default that can handle writing values of type `Integer` to a request body.

As you said, you can handle this situation by changing the `count` to be a `String`. After all, there is no `Integer` type in HTTP request parameters. However, you were worried

> But I might need to pass complex data types as parameters later.

Assume something like this

```
public @ResponseBody MyResponse processRequest(String RequestId, int count, Complex complex) {
```

with

```
public class Complex {
    private String someValue;
    private int intValue;

    public String getSomeValue() {
        return someValue;
    }

    public void setSomeValue(String someValue) {
        this.someValue = someValue;
    }

    public int getIntValue() {
        return intValue;
    }

    public void setIntValue(int intValue) {
        this.intValue = intValue;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return someValue + " " + intValue;
    }
}
```

The the following will work just fine

```
MultiValueMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
map.add("RequestId", "asd");
map.add("count", "42");
map.add("someValue", "complex");
map.add("intValue", "69");
restTemplate.postForObject(url, map,MyResponse.class);
```

Remember that the request parameters are used to populate the fields of model attributes by their names.

An even better solution would have you using a serialization standard like JSON or XML.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. By "using a serialization standard like JSON or XML.", you mean that I should create a request object having RequestId,count and someValue as memebers. and post that object. controller should have the params as RequestBody MyClass myobject?

Comment: @aks No, I mean instead of sending request parameters, you should send JSON and XML. Spring supports those types with `@RequestBody` annotation on handler method parameters.