# Send multipart file via RestTemplate

Tags: android, spring, rest, resttemplate, spring-android

i have some problem about send image file (multipart) using android via Spring restTemplate.

here is my controller on server :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadPhoto/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<String> uploadPhoto(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile srcFile,
                                               @PathVariable("id") Integer id) {

///  do something

        return RestUtil.getJsonSHttptatus(HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
    }
```

and this is rest request in my android activity

private void doUpload(){

```
        new AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                FormHttpMessageConverter formHttpMessageConverter = new FormHttpMessageConverter();
                formHttpMessageConverter.setCharset(Charset.forName("UTF8"));


                RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();


                restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add( formHttpMessageConverter );
                restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());


                restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());

                String uri = "http://localhost:8089/web/uploadPhoto/1";

                String imagePath = "/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20140406_130350.jpg";

                MultiValueMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
                map.add("expenseId", 1);
                map.add("file", new FileSystemResource(path));

                HttpHeaders imageHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
                imageHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

                HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> imageEntity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>(map, imageHeaders);



                restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, imageEntity, Boolean.class);


                return "";
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data : "+result,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }.execute();
    }
```

I get this error :

```
04-07 07:21:00.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1205): Caused by: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [java.lang.Integer]
04-07 07:21:00.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.writePart(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:314)
04-07 07:21:00.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.writeParts(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:276)
04-07 07:21:00.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.writeMultipart(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:266)
04-07 07:21:00.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.write(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:209)
04-07 07:21:00.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.write(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:91)
04-07 07:21:00.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$HttpEntityRequestCallback.doWithRequest(RestTemplate.java:624)
04-07 07:21:00.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:474)
04-07 07:21:00.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:439)
04-07 07:21:00.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:415)
04-07 07:21:00.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at com.sample.rest.client.MainActivity$4.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:295)
04-07 07:21:00.312: E/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at com.sample.rest.client.MainActivity$4.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
```

Whats wrong with my code ?
Any HttpMessageConverter for Multipart Request ?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FormHttpMessageConverter` cannot write the `expenseId` part because it is an integer. Try sending it as a String:

```
map.add("expenseId", "1");
```

And receiving as a String:

```
@PathVariable("id") String id
```

There is a very similar question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20479074/spring-restremplate-postforobject-with-request-parameter-having-integer-value/20482232#20482232).

Comment: Excellent, happy to help! If you don't mind, can you accept my answer?

Comment: @RoyClarkson I can't send the file name with the file when using the above code getting HTTP Status 400 - The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect error.No problem when i upload only the file.